# Shall I oil new longboard bearings?

Tags: equipment, maintenance, longboarding

I've bought new bearings and I am not sure if it is supposed to be oiled before usage :/

When bought my longboard, it was already set up. So I only have experience from cleaning and oiling the old ones.

Comment: A do not think i applies only to LONGBOARD bearings :/

Comment: If they are shielded on both sides, I would probably say no. (IF they are sealed, then they aren't designed for this anyway.) If they're open on one side, I'd say yeah, oil them.

Comment: @jedd.ahyoung: Can you pleas write it as an Answer so i can close this question. thx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@Mailo You must've solve this one but as it hasn't been answered for long time.

The most important thing to consider is the bearing you bought is [pre-lubricated or not](http://reviewlongboards.com/best-longboard-bearings/). As most bearings come pre-lubricated. Pre-lubrication meanings that the bearings will spin faster right out of the box. However, with the low price of skateboard oil, if a bearing does not come pre-lubricated buying that may be good idea.

But remember [cleaning and lubricating are not the same thing](http://www.rollerskatenation.com/bearings-faq/). And if you like you can visit [this website](https://lushlongboards.com/workshops/how-to-clean-bearings/), and [this website](http://www.skatetheeast.net/2011/07/tutorial-how-to-clean-your-longboard-bearings/) for tutorial on how to clean bearings.

Comment: I guess I was not explicit enough in my question ;) The question should probably be "How to say if it is pre-lubricated"

Comment: @Mailo Although it is not mention in question, will search for that and let you know.